# Blank Terminal?

Tags: command-line

I can open the terminal on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but it's completely blank and there appears to be no way to input anything.

I tried typing just in case there was something hidden, but it's as though the font is black on black. I've also tried changing font colours, but it didn't do anything.

How do I get to see what I'm doing (or what I did do that screw it up)?

Comment: I figured it out (sort of)
Opened terminal, went to Edit, Profile Preferences, Color, un-check 'use colors from system theme,  changed font colour to Yellow and background colour to black
Strange thing though, I have no idea how everything got switched to 'grey' yet came out as black on black?

Comment: Also can try to blindly type `xterm` and press enter.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1418553 This answer on the other question solved the issue for me

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was a previous command that had crashed. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> broke out of it for me. Perhaps something everybody knows, but not me until now!

Answer (score 3):

Open virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.Then run the following commands to reinstall `gnome-terminal`,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

To return to GUI press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

It can be possible because of previous command crashed or not run successfully, and terminal has been closed OR forcefully closed. FATAL error can also play role for such scenario. You can try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

OR You can reinstall `gnome-terminal` by using virtual terminal.

OR **Backup** your current .bashrc file:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
```

Copy the skeleton .bashrc file over yours:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Afterwards, load the new one:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I went to terminal **Preferences** by right clicking on the terminal and choosing the **Preferences** option. Then I went to the **Command** tab and unchecked **Run a custom command instead of my shell**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks, I mess up with that setting yesterday and Im totally freaking out when seeing the blank terminal, 

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

From [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377616/blank-terminal#comment482289_377616):

> I figured it out (sort of). Opened terminal, went to *Edit*, *Profile Preferences*, *Color*, un-checked *Use colors from system theme*, changed font colour to *Yellow* and background colour to *Black*.
>
> Strange thing though, I have no idea how everything got switched to 'grey' yet came out as black on black!