# Cannot write into terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

After starting terminal the cursor appears, but cannot type any character. I tried:

1. To start Midnight Commander from Application list, but only blank terminal window started with blinking cursor;
2. Installed Terminator, but starting it still a cursor appeared. Couldn't type anything, too.
3. In IntelliJ IDEA I opened Console, but the symptoms were the same.
4. Pressing ctrl+alt+F3 I could log in to tty3, the prompt appeared but couldn't type...

The keyboard works as usual...
Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image: IntelliJ IDEA's console]

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with the startup files like `/etc/profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc. etc. You haven't mentioned what did you do before this problem started. You can try with a newly created user.

Comment: @FedKad Thank you! I created simple test user and the Terminal worked as usual but with my account still not working.

Comment: I would start comparing "start-up" script files in the users' home directories: `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases`, `.bash_completion`, ...

Comment: Thank you @FedKad I checked those files.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @FedKad, I found the solution: in `.bashrc` I deleted the following lines:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

and now it works perfectly!

Comment: Yes this was the fix for my issue.

Comment: Yes this fixed my issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the solution if you want to keep Angular CLI autocompletion:

1. Find the `source <(some command)` line in your `.bashrc`, in this case `ng completion script`
2. In another terminal, run `some command > ~/.ng.autocompletion.for.bashrc`
3. Replace the original `source <(some command)` line with `source ~/.ng.autocompletion.for.bashrc`

These steps will precalculate the output of the `ng completion script` command. There shouldn't be any major disadvantages with this because the output `ng completion script` is just a small wrapper that calls the actual `ng --get-yargs-completions`. In the unlikely case an Angular update breaks it, you can rerun step 2.

The cause of the original problem is that `ng` is written in Javascript running on Node.js, and Node.js programs are slow because they have to load a bunch of files from disk ([my related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500576/1004020)).