# Cannot type anything in Terminal

Tags: command-line, freeze

After I have installed 'Google CLI' I cannot do anything in the terminal.
I have tried a few solution I found on web to recover, but still without success.

[image]

Comment: What is your OS? What is "'Google CLI"?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 22.04; Google CLI is a tool for developers to play with Google features

Comment: What happens when you press Enter? Does the cursor move?

Comment: Nothing. I have try to use ENTER, Ctr + C/Q/S/Z/C/J; 
I have tried to use bash/Javascript terminal -> the same story

Comment: Can you get TUI login prompt by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 or Ctrl+Alt+F4? What happens after login there?

Comment: I have tried too -  the same behavior: after login the coursor is just blinking, I cannot type / go to next line

Comment: Probably your user profile files have been altered with commands that cause the hang. You should check the `.profile` and `.bash*` files and revert the changes.

Comment: I have tried it...but seems I have no knowledge how to read it.
I have tried to restore it from /etc/SKEL  folder but maybe I paste it in wrong folder ?
Where I should paste 'original' file .. in /etc/  ?

Comment: Thank you FedKad for you effort and wanting to help

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418431/cannot-write-into-terminal

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**: under `/home/MY_PROFILE` folder in file `.bashrc` I had to comment next line:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion. 
#source <(ng completion script)
```