# Linux terminal not working; no file paths are showing with no response to keyboard inputs

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

My terminal in Ubuntu is not working, it is not responding to keyboard nor does it shows any file paths as well. This issue is reflected is in the VS Code terminal as well. [image: My termial]

Comment: Did you mean to use the tag 22.04 instead of 12.04?

Comment: Sorry my version is 20.04, I'll change the tag now.

Comment: Check the `~/.bashrc` file and other automatically sourced files ... Rename them and restart your terminal to see if it opens correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot write into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418431/cannot-write-into-terminal)